# Commanding with Static Items of Listbox using MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox, selecteditem

I have a list box in my view with three static items(Name,Age,Gender), and I want my ViewModel to do something when an item in the ListBox is selected. I want to do this without any code-behind, using the MVVM pattern.

My goal is to navigate to a page when an item is selected also the items stated above does not come from an observable list, it is hardcoded in my XAML. How would I do that? Please teach me. If you don't mind to send a sample, that would be a great help. Thanks much in advance.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbviewlist">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged" >
            <Command:EventToCommand Command ="{Binding ViewCommand}"
                PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ListBox.Items>
        <StackPanel  x:Name="lbiview1" Orientation="Vertical">
            <ListBoxItem Content="Name" FontSize="35" Margin="10,0,0,0"
                Foreground="OrangeRed"/>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="View name of the patient"  
                FontSize="25"  Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="White"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="lbiview2" Orientation="Vertical">
            <ListBoxItem Content="Age"  FontSize="35" Margin="10,20,0,0"
                Foreground="OrangeRed"/>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="View age of the patient"  
                FontSize="25"  Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="White"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="lbiview3"  Orientation="Vertical">
            <ListBoxItem Content="Gender" FontSize="35" Margin="10,20,0,0"
                Foreground="OrangeRed"/>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="View the gender of the patient"
                FontSize="25" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="White"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListBox.Items>                    
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use data binding to bind the `SelectedItem` of the `ListBox` to a property on your view model. Then, in the setter of your view model property, you can run the logic you need to when the selected item changes.

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}" ... />
```

**Update**

Ok, firstly I would strongly recommend (no insist) that you use an MVVM framework. [If you're doing MVVM, then you need to use a framework](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/UsingTheMVVMPatternRequiresAFramework.aspx).

Next, there's no reason why these list items can't be on your view model. It would certainly make your view a lot cleaner.

Then you can set your `ListBox` `ItemsSource` to bind to your view model collection, and then use data templating in your view to render each item in the list consistently.

E.g. your view can end up something like:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"  ... />
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" ... />
          </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Much cleaner, I think you'll agree.

Comment: Would you mind to send me an example? thanks much for the help. I just don't know where and how to start. By the way, I see different examples in the internet, however my problem is that I don't have an IObservable collection that can be bind to the property since my items are hard coded. See may XAML. Thanks again

Comment: What are _view1, _view2, and _view3?

Comment: those were just strings that I put in Resources.xaml :)

I can change it directly to the actual string/name of the item. See updated XAML. Thanks Again!

Comment: I strongly agree, but my problem is I was asked by my boss to the hardcoded way since it is static and not to put it in a list. :(

Is there a way to bind myselecteditem to my static/hardcoded items?

Lastly, (Apologies for too many questions) how to implement the MySelectedItem? I mean the syntax. I really apologize as I just started to learn Windows phone development lately. Thanks my friend.

Comment: The requirement from your boss is that the data is static, he doesn't (nor shouldn't) specify how to implement it, that's your responsibility. The data can still be static using this method, it's just the definition of that static data has been moved from the view to the view model.

Comment: If you insist on the items being in the view, then you can still use this method, the only difference is that the collection of objects used for the ItemsSource would be a resource in your view, rather than a property on your view model.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28646/discussion-between-jennyjane-and-devdigital)